# Change Website Screenshot to 3D Perspective

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, perspective

Using Photoshop I want to mimic what moz.com does with their product tour. I have a screen shot of my website and I want change the perspective to look like this:

http://moz.com/products/tour

What's the best method for this to maintain a legible version of my screenshot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing that you already have a base plane with the right perspective (you can use a photo or make a quick render in Blender).

Use the free transform tools (ctrl-click on the points to change the perspective) and make the points match the template picture you did before. Do this in one step to prevent the image to be re-interpolated further.

Tip:
Edit/Preferences/General you have the option to set image interpolation, choose Bicubic sharper to keep your typography as cleaner as you can get.

Comment: I think I need to play with Perspective to really get a feel for how it will change the perspective (in other words where to adjust to get the correct planar view) but the Bi-Cubic Sharper comment was a great tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Download the PSD from here and put up your screenshot as @mildtaste suggested http://epfpk.org/backdrop.psd . This psd is just to speedup your work just in case you don't know blender.

Comment: Thank you very much. Along with mildtaste's answer this is pretty much a dead ringer for the moz.com cubic look. Thank you.